# Passing Content between two Windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is, to pass some information from a WPF window to an existing WPF page. I would like to open a the window by pressing a button on WPF Page1.
Then, i have to get all the text stored in Textbox1 to a variable in Page1. But only when the user presses ButtonXY on the "Window". How can i solve this Problem without using the "Bindings" because there has to be abig "Switch" clause next to Page1?

Comment: simply pass on your model to the second window then handle the update on the second window then you wont need to pass along anything they will both have all the data at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM then both the window and the page could have a common ViewModel and those TextBoxes should be bound to the same property with UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged and this way no more events or notifications are needed.

Otherwise, sometimes i tend to create a global project which will be added as a references where needed. This way, you will be able to set events and their handlers to accomplish your specific issues. I think this is not an elegant solution but it helps me a lot communicating between different projects or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class that will contain all your data you want to transfer between all your windows.

```
public  YourNewClassWithSettings
{
   string StringNumber1;
   string StringNumber2;
}
```

Create an instance of this class in your main window and set the values of the properties you want.

Pass the instance of YourNewClassWithSettings by reference to your constructor of your next window.

```
YourNewClassWithSettings test = new YourNewClassWithSettings();
test.StringNumber1 = "mySetting";

WindowControl w = new WindowControl(ref test);
w.ShowDialog();

//See what was changed!!!!
string changedValue = test.StringNumber1; //Will be "IamDone"
```

In your constructor you would say:

```
public WindowControl(ref YourNewClassWithSettings test)
{
   // example: You can now say TextBox1.Text =  test.StringNumber1;

   // Whatever you change here like test.
   test.StringNumber1 = "IamDone";
   //When you close this window, because test was passed by ref : you
   // will see StringNumber1 = "IamDone" in your main window again
   //when accessing the property of that class. Always pass by ref
   this.Close();
}
```

This is the MVVM approach.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a `MainWindow` and a `SubWindow`.

Your `SubWindow` contains a `Button` and a `Textbox`. When you click on the `Button` in the `SubWindow` you want to transfer the `Text` from the `Textbox` into the `MainWindow`.

**Main Window.** 
You implment a `Property` (a Getter and Setter) wich will contain the transfered `Text` string. The `MainWindow` contains also the `SubWindow`! Don't forget to pass the `MainWindow` into the `SubWindow` Constructor (look below) so the `SubWindow` know the `MainWindow` instance

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    private Window subWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        subWindow = new SubWindow(this);

        subWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**SubWindow**

```
public partial class SubWindow : Window
{
    private Window mainWindow;

    public SubWindow(Window mainWindow)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonTransferTheData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindow.Text = myTextBoxInSubWindow.Text;
    }
}
```

Your `SubWindow` knows the `MainWindow`. So you can access the `Text Property`. On the Button click you wirte the `Text` from the `Textbox` into the `Property` of the `MainWindow`.

**HINT**
The `mainWindow.Text = myTextBoxInSubWindow.Text;` line could throw an exception. this is because you want to access a thread from another.
So you need to dispatch it. Change this line into:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => mainWindow.Text = myTextBoxInSubWindow.Text);
```

Hope this helps.